# How to check if a dictionary has exact same keys in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to check if a dictionary contains the exact same keys as in a list of keys (no more, no less). I'm currently using `all()` and a length check to do this.  Is there a better way? Thanks!

```
d = {'1': 'one', '3': 'three', '2': 'two'}

key_list = ['1', '2', '3']

all(col in d for col in key_list) and len(d) == 3
True
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about

```
set(d) == set(key_list)
```

`set(d)` is equals to `set(d.keys())` as @gmds pointed out

Comment: Much more succinct than my answer

Comment: You can just use `set(d)`, since iteration over a `dict` is over its keys by default.

Comment: Does ```set()``` guarantees the key order on a dict?

Comment: `set` nor `dict` is about ordering

Comment: Two sets are equal if and only if every element of each set is contained in the other (each is a subset of the other). From the doc. Nothing about the order.

Answer (score 0):

A list is great for maintaining order, but a `set` is far better for checking membership:

```py
d = {'1': 'one', '3': 'three', '2': 'two'}

key_list = set(['1', '2', '3'])

all(col in d for col in key_list) and len(d) == 3
```

`set` has a lookup time of O(1), compared to `list` which is O(N)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> d = {'1': 'one', '3': 'three', '2': 'two'}
>>> key_list = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> sorted(d) == sorted(key_list)
True
>>>
```